# JPA, three entities, their relations. ¿CascadeType for delete correctly?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this three entities, that have their own table in a DB. The principal entities are `Wearable` and `Job`. Keep in mind that the CascadeType set in this code are wrong.

```
@Entity
public class Wearable {

  @Id
  private String mac;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wearable")
  private List<Job> jobs;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wearable", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<WearableSubscription> subscriptions;

}


@Entity
public class Job {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "job", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private WearableSubscription wearableSubscription;

}
```

Then I want to stablish a relation (`WearableSubscription`) between `Wearable` and a `Job`. Wearable can have many `WearableSubscription` but, only one of this `WearableSubscription` can have one `Job`.

```
@Entity
public class WearableSubscription {

  private WearableSubscriptionId id;

  @OneToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Job job;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JoinColumn(name = "wearable_mac", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Wearable wearable;

  private String message;
  private String imageUrl;
  private String audioUrl;
```

}

So at this point, I don't know exactly how CascadeType works. I mean, if I want to delete a `WearableSubscription` without deleting the `Wearable` and the `Job`, what types of Cascade I have to set in all of this fields? I'm trying all combinations and in some situations I delete all (WSub, W and J) and in others, when I perform the delete nothing occurs and all (WSub, W and J) stills at the DB.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [Cascade Type](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/KDJJR/ejb3_overview_meta_field.html#N10EFD), you have a plethora of values you can pass on as an array to the `cascade` argument.

If all you want to **NOT** cascade are the DELETE operations, don't pass `CascadeType.ALL` (as it includes `CascadeType.REMOVE`) nor `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

Cascading occurs from an Entity which contains other entites. Since your `WearableSubscription` is a relationship entity you may not want to cascade operations made to it, as the changes are only relevant to the relation and not the entities themselves.

So, in your `WearableSubscription` class you want both `Job` and `Wearable` to have no cascade settings, and leave the other classes as is.

Hope this helps.